# `\mainmatter` changes counter format to default with `memoir`

Tags: memoir, counters

Adding `\mainmatter` in the following code clears the counter format for figures. Is there a way to keep both `\mainmatter` and the new counter format?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter-\arabic{figure}}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{One}
test
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{10.png} \caption{} \label{handle}
\end{figure}
Image \ref{handle}.
\end{document}
```

This code must access an image named `10.png`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the line (may be again)

```
 \renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter-\arabic{figure}}
```

after `\mainmatter` like

```
\mainmatter
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter-\arabic{figure}}
```